# Error: Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a `data.frame` object

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, tidyverse

I am trying to create a separate column that includes the minimum value of two other columns. When triad is equal to "triad_ah", I want to get the minimum value of the following two columns.

My data looks like the following:

```
triad         convince_animals  convince_health 
triad_ah      4                 5
not_triad_ah  2                 3
```

This is the output I would like:

```
triad         convince_animals  convince_health  convince_min
triad_ah      4                 5                4
not_triad_ah  2                 3                99
```

I have attempted this in two ways. I think the way using case_when is likely to be neater. I have also included the error messages I get for each of these.

**Attempt 1**

```
dflong$convince_min <- dflong %>%
  case_when( 
    .$triad == "triad_ah" ~ min(.$convince_animals, .$convince_health), 
    .$triad == TRUE ~ 99
  )

Error: Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a `data.frame` object.
```

**Attempt 2**

```
dflong$convince_min <- dflong %>%
  ifelse(dflong$triad == "triad_ah", min(dflong$convince_animals, dflong$convince_health), 99)

Error in ifelse(., dflong$triad == "triad_ah", min(dflong$convince_animals, : unused argument (99)
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Data:

```
structure(list(triad = c("triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", 
"triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_ah", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", 
"triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_hm", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", "triad_eh", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", "triad_am", 
"triad_am", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_em", 
"triad_em", "triad_em", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae", 
"triad_ae", "triad_ae", "triad_ae"), convince_animals = c(2, 
5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 
6, 6, 7, 5, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 
1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 1, 
5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 
4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 
2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 4, 
4, 7, 2, 3, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 
7, 5, 5, 2, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 
3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 
5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 6, 7, 5, 1, 
5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 
3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 
5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 
7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 
5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 3, 
7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, 4, 
7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 
2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 6, 7, 5, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 
4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 
3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 
3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 
4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 
7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 
7, 7, 3, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 
4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 
5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 
4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 6, 7, 5, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 
2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 
4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 
7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 
5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3, 6, 6, 
3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 
6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 
7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 
2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 
2, 6, 6, 7, 5, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 
5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 
1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 
2, 4, 6, 4, 1, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 
7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 
5, 2, 5, 4, 7, 2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 
4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 
3, 7, 5, 5, 2, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 
6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 4, 
6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 1, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 7, 2, 6, 6, 7, 5, 
1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 
6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 6, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 2, 2, 3, 
4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 1, 
6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4, 2, 6, 3, 
4, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 7, 
2, 5, 4, 4, 6, 3, 7, 7, 3, 6, 6, 3, 7, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 
3, 7, 5, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 7, 3, 7, 5, 5, 2, 
4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 
4, 2, 7, 5, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 5, 3), convince_health = c(6, 5, 7, 
5, 6, 2, 7, 6, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 7, 
7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 7, 
3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 6, 
7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 
6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 6, 
6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 
4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 
3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 2, 7, 6, 
4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 
6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 
7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 
4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 
2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 
5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 
4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 2, 7, 6, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 
6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 
6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 
4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 
6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 
7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 
6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 
5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 
6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 
6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 2, 7, 6, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 
6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 
7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 
5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 
5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 
7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 
7, 5, 6, 2, 7, 6, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 
7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 
7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 
6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 
5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 
6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 
7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 
7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 
7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 
5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5, 7, 5, 6, 2, 7, 
6, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 7, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 
2, 6, 7, 7, 6, 4, 6, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 5, 
5, 4, 7, 4, 6, 7, 4, 7, 4, 6, 3, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 
5, 2, 6, 7, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 7, 2, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 
7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 
6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 4, 7, 5, 6, 
3, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 6, 6, 
6, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 5, 6, 4, 7, 5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1230L))
```

Comment: Note: your error about the two-sided formula was because you were "piping" `dflong` directly into `case_when`. That means `dflong` was being treated as "Case 1," resulting in your error. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the "typical" tidyverse syntax for this case:

```
dflong <- dflong %>%
  mutate(convince_min = case_when( 
    triad == "triad_ah" ~ pmin(convince_animals, convince_health), 
    TRUE ~ 99
  ))
```

### notes

- It isn't necessary to prefix the column names with `.$` because of [tidy evaluation](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/).
- I've replaced the second condition `triad == TRUE` with `TRUE` because this is a "catch-all" condition that will account for all cases except `triad == "triad_ah"`. The order of conditions in `case_when()` should go from most specific to most general.
- I've replaced `min()` with `pmin()` which compares the two columns, returning the minimum value of each of the two elements at position `i` of the columns, for all `i`.

Comment: What's the difference between min() and pmin()?

Comment: The p stands for "parallel." `pmin()` takes any number of vectors as arguments. It will go through the vectors in parallel, and get the minimum value at each position. That's needed in your case because you want a vector of minimum values. `min()` will give a single value, the minimum value found across both vectors.